# Ubuntu Server Super Slow after reboot

Tags: server, 20.04, startup, reboot

My Ubuntu Server 20.04 has been running pretty fast until a reboot about 10-15 minutes ago, at the time this was written, it took it about 3-5 minutes to shutdown and about 1-3 to start back up, now everything I do is super slow, my website is not loading, it takes about 5-10 seconds to run `ls` I am looking for direction, I have a good about of ram, about 8GB and I had 50GB of SWAP space, I also have 2 HDD and 1 SSD. Any guidance will be helpful! Thank you. If you need/want any logs or files, I will be more than happy to get them to you.

top

```
top - 19:42:00 up  1:43,  2 users,  load average: 0.40, 0.44, 0.57
Tasks: 216 total,   1 running, 215 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  1.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 93.3 id,  4.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7833.5 total,   4891.3 free,   1260.4 used,   1681.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  65536.0 total,  64037.3 free,   1498.7 used.   6287.4 avail Mem 
 Unknown command - try 'h' for help 
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                             
   2835 root      20   0  437496   3492   2036 S   3.0   0.0   2:17.34 ebpf.plugin                                                                                                                         
   2836 netdata   20   0   55524   5244   2008 S   2.0   0.1   1:31.61 apps.plugin                                                                                                                         
   2618 netdata   20   0  343024  87172   4060 S   1.0   1.1   0:57.31 netdata                                                                                                                             
    923 root      20   0  838872  16224   6192 S   0.3   0.2   0:12.16 f2b/server                                                                                                                          
   1066 mysql     20   0 1736500  48264   9200 S   0.3   0.6   5:17.49 mysqld                                                                                                                              
   2841 netdata   20   0  725444  11980   5240 S   0.3   0.1   1:24.26 go.d.plugin                                                                                                                         
  11134 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.07 kworker/1:3-events                                                                                                                  
      1 root      20   0  168612   9160   6308 S   0.0   0.1   0:03.88 systemd                                                                                                                             
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                            
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                              
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                          
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                
      8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                                        
      9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.79 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                         
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:01.32 rcu_sched                                                                                                                           
     11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 migration/0                                                                                                                         
     12 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                                       
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                             
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                                                             
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                                                                       
     17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.31 migration/1                                                                                                                         
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.76 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                         
     20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                
     21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                                                                                                           
     22 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                                                                               
     23 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_kthre                                                                                                                     
     24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kauditd                                                                                                                             
     26 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd                                                                                                                          
     27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 oom_reaper                                                                                                                          
     28 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 writeback                                                                                                                           
     29 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kcompactd0                                                                                                                          
     30 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksmd                                                                                                                                
     31 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 khugepaged                                                                                                                          
    123 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd                                                                                                                         
    124 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kblockd                                                                                                                             
    125 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 blkcg_punt_bio                                                                                                                      
    126 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 tpm_dev_wq                                                                                                                          
    127 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff                                                                                                                             
    128 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 md                                                                                                                                  
    129 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 edac-poller                                                                                                                         
    130 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 devfreq_wq                                                                                                                          
    131 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 watchdogd                                                                                                                           
    132 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:08.56 kswapd0                                                                                                                             
    133 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ecryptfs-kthrea                                                                                                                     
    136 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld                                                                                                                            
    138 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 acpi_thermal_pm                                                                                                                     
    139 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 scsi_eh_0                                                                                                                           
    140 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_0                                                                                                                          
    141 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.05 scsi_eh_1                                                                                                                           
    142 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_1                                                                                                                          
    145 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 scsi_eh_2                                                                                                                           
    146 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_2                                                                                                                          
    147 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 scsi_eh_3                                                                                                                           
    148 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_3                                                                                                                          
    150 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 scsi_eh_4                                                                                                                           
    151 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_4
```

syslog

```
Aug 26 19:38:49 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: warning: maildrop/4BcGLg6Sy7z1P6tS: error writing 4BcGPj2rstz1P6tV: queue file write error
Aug 26 19:38:50 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: 4BcGPk2sYtz1P6tV: uid=0 from=<root>
Aug 26 19:38:50 mail postfix/cleanup[10988]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mail.sturtz.ml"
Aug 26 19:38:50 mail postfix/cleanup[10988]: warning: 4BcGPk2sYtz1P6tV: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Aug 26 19:38:50 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: warning: maildrop/4BcGCl3HKWz1P6tL: error writing 4BcGPk2sYtz1P6tV: queue file write error
Aug 26 19:38:51 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: 4BcGPl2tGlz1P6tV: uid=0 from=<root>
Aug 26 19:38:51 mail postfix/cleanup[10817]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mail.sturtz.ml"
Aug 26 19:38:51 mail postfix/cleanup[10817]: warning: 4BcGPl2tGlz1P6tV: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Aug 26 19:38:51 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: warning: maildrop/4BcGJP0tXyz1P6tQ: error writing 4BcGPl2tGlz1P6tV: queue file write error
Aug 26 19:38:52 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: 4BcGPm2v3Sz1P6tV: uid=0 from=<root>
Aug 26 19:38:52 mail postfix/cleanup[10988]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mail.sturtz.ml"
Aug 26 19:38:52 mail postfix/cleanup[10988]: warning: 4BcGPm2v3Sz1P6tV: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Aug 26 19:38:52 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: warning: maildrop/4BcGP05FY8z1P6tR: error writing 4BcGPm2v3Sz1P6tV: queue file write error
Aug 26 19:38:53 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: 4BcGPn2vlhz1P6tV: uid=0 from=<root>
Aug 26 19:38:53 mail postfix/cleanup[10817]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mail.sturtz.ml"
Aug 26 19:38:53 mail postfix/cleanup[10817]: warning: 4BcGPn2vlhz1P6tV: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Aug 26 19:38:53 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: warning: maildrop/4BcFwl1Dkmz1P6t1: error writing 4BcGPn2vlhz1P6tV: queue file write error
Aug 26 19:38:54 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: 4BcGPp2wX8z1P6tV: uid=0 from=<root>
Aug 26 19:38:54 mail postfix/cleanup[10988]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mail.sturtz.ml"
Aug 26 19:38:54 mail postfix/cleanup[10988]: warning: 4BcGPp2wX8z1P6tV: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Aug 26 19:38:54 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: warning: maildrop/4BcFKb1RZqz1P6sP: error writing 4BcGPp2wX8z1P6tV: queue file write error
Aug 26 19:38:55 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: 4BcGPq2xQQz1P6tV: uid=0 from=<root>
Aug 26 19:39:01 mail CRON[11024]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/fail2ban_banned_db unban_db)
Aug 26 19:39:01 mail CRON[11030]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Aug 26 19:39:02 mail systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 26 19:39:02 mail systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 26 19:39:02 mail systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Aug 26 19:39:43 mail postfix/master[2610]: warning: unix_trigger_event: read timeout for service public/pickup
Aug 26 19:40:01 mail CRON[11166]: (www-data) CMD (php -f /var/www/nextcloud/cron.php)
Aug 26 19:40:01 mail CRON[11167]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/fail2ban_banned_db unban_db)
Aug 26 19:40:43 mail postfix/master[2610]: warning: unix_trigger_event: read timeout for service public/pickup
Aug 26 19:41:01 mail CRON[11214]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/fail2ban_banned_db unban_db)
Aug 26 19:41:04 mail postfix/proxymap[6357]: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1:3306: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (110)
Aug 26 19:41:04 mail postfix/cleanup[10817]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mail.sturtz.ml"
Aug 26 19:41:04 mail postfix/cleanup[10817]: warning: 4BcGPq2xQQz1P6tV: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Aug 26 19:41:04 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: warning: maildrop/4BcG1N5yKQz1P6t8: error writing 4BcGPq2xQQz1P6tV: queue file write error
Aug 26 19:41:04 mail postfix/pickup[7411]: 4BcGSJ5QClz1P6tV: uid=997 from=<netdata>
Aug 26 19:41:43 mail postfix/master[2610]: warning: unix_trigger_event: read timeout for service public/pickup
Aug 26 19:42:02 mail CRON[11299]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/fail2ban_banned_db unban_db)
Aug 26 19:42:43 mail postfix/master[2610]: warning: unix_trigger_event: read timeout for service public/pickup
Aug 26 19:43:01 mail CRON[11350]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/fail2ban_banned_db unban_db)
Aug 26 19:43:15 mail postfix/proxymap[6357]: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1:3306: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (110)
Aug 26 19:43:15 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[11236]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_maillist.cf lookup error for "*"
```

Other requested data

root@mail:/var/log# free -h

```
           total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available 
Mem:       7.6Gi       1.2Gi       4.8Gi        27Mi       1.6Gi       6.1Gi 
Swap:       63Gi       1.5Gi        62Gi
```

root@mail:/var/log# grep -i swap /etc/fstab

```
 /dev/disk/by-uuid/0edf561f-17da-4d10-89f3-45f3abb4ee82 none swap sw 0 0 
 /swap.img  none    swap    sw  0   0
```

root@mail:/var/log# ls -al /swap.img

```
-rw------- 1 root root 4294967296 Aug 25 01:26 /swap.img
```

Comment: What have you checked to try and find the problem on your own? Why 50G swap? Edit your question and show me `top`... as a text copy/paste... not a screenshot please. What does syslog have to say?

Comment: ok, and the 50GB swap because I thought that that would help make my server faster

Comment: Done, about the 50gb swap, I thought by doing that I was adding 50gb to my ram

Comment: Thanks for the data... however, your `top` command output is incomplete... and your syslog snippet doesn't show any error. See my partial answer, below.

Comment: For each of your HDD/SSD, edit your question with screenshots of the `Disks` app SMART DATA scrollable window. Which is your boot disk?

Comment: I dont have a GUI

Comment: here is the top command

Comment: @heynnema Is this better?

Comment: Lots of postfix and mysql errors in syslog. It looks like probably mysql isn't running. You'll have to troubleshoot that later.

Comment: ok this is what I get for mysql

Comment: ```
Aug 26 17:59:22 mail.sturtz.ml systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.22 database server...
Aug 26 17:59:40 mail.sturtz.ml mysqld[1066]: 2020-08-26 17:59:40 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.22-MariaDB-1ubuntu1) starting as process 1066 ...
Aug 26 17:59:58 mail.sturtz.ml systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3.22 database server.
Aug 26 18:00:00 mail.sturtz.ml /etc/mysql/debian-start[2455]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Aug 26 18:00:00 mail.sturtz.ml /etc/mysql/debian-start[2455]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
```

Comment: `
Aug 26 18:00:00 mail.sturtz.ml /etc/mysql/debian-start[2455]: Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
Aug 26 18:00:00 mail.sturtz.ml /etc/mysql/debian-start[2455]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Aug 26 18:00:00 mail.sturtz.ml /etc/mysql/debian-start[2455]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
Aug 26 18:00:00 mail.sturtz.ml debian-start[2632]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

HP Compaq 6000 Pro SFF

You have BIOS version 01.09, dated 08/25/2009.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 02.03 Rev A, dated 11/27/2015, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-compaq-6000-pro-small-form-factor-pc/4024462).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Note: To update the BIOS, you'll either need Windows, or FreeDOS on a USB flash key, or check if the HP BIOS has a way to update directly from the BIOS itself.

**swap**

Your swap is excessive at 65G.

You have ~60G swap on /dev/sda5, and ~4G swap in /swap.img.

We'll eliminate the ~60G swap on /dev/sda5, and run on just the 4G swap in /swap.img. You can use the ~60G /dev/sda5 partition for something else later.

`sudo swapoff -a`           # turn off swap

Edit /etc/fstab:

`sudo pico /etc/fstab`

Comment out this line:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0edf561f-17da-4d10-89f3-45f3abb4ee82 none swap sw 0 0
```

Save the file.

`sudo swapon /swap.img` # turn on swap with just /swap.img

Now `free -h` should look approximately like this:

```
           total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available 
Mem:       7.6Gi       1.2Gi       4.8Gi        27Mi       1.6Gi       6.1Gi 
Swap:        4Gi         0Gi         4Gi
```

**postfix/mysql**

I see lots of postfix and mysql errors in /var/log/syslog. You'll have to troubleshoot that later. Ask a new question if need be. Look into why it looks like mysql is not running.

**SSD vs HDD**

Right now you're booting off of a HDD.

To further speed up your system, consider changing the configuration so that you boot off of SSD, and make the HDD a data drive. In other words... rebuild the system from scratch.

Comment: ```root@mail:/var/log# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.6Gi       1.2Gi       4.8Gi        27Mi       1.6Gi       6.1Gi
Swap:          63Gi       1.5Gi        62Gi
root@mail:/var/log# 
```

Comment: ```root@mail:/var/log# grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0edf561f-17da-4d10-89f3-45f3abb4ee82 none swap sw 0 0
/swap.img none swap sw 0 0```

Comment: And how do you update bios?

Comment: Thanks for the data... but it shouldn't be in the comments, but rather, as an edit to your question. Makes it much easier to read.

Comment: Do you have Windows installed?

Comment: ok, I will edit that., I do not have a GUI, I have ubuntu server, the computer I am on RN is a MacBook

Comment: Show me `ls -al /swap.img`.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112313/discussion-between-nathaniel-sturtz-and-heynnema